# JQuery breaks all scripts on page in ie7 only

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this included in the scripts used all of the jquery on the page stop working but only in ie7, as soon as I remove it they all start working again.

```
  function go_standards()
  {
    var audit_id = $('#auditID').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax/create_audit_ajax.php",
    data: $('#audit_form').serialize(),
    success:function(response){
        window.location = "../standards.php?page=create_audit&auditID="+audit_id;
    },
  });
 }
```

The button it is bound to

```
    <input type="button" name="standard" id="standard"
         class="control_submit standard_btn" value="" onClick="go_standards()" >
```

I have tried removing the extra comma from the last argument, using it on the external script it was originally and then putting in the header of the page instead.  There aren't any error messages, nothing.

I am running it on ie7 on a vm and there are no f12 developer tools to see if there are any errors etc

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Well, 3 right answers, there you go

Comment: It doesn't get much better than that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE8 and below version give error on trailing extra comma.

Extra comma at end may cause issue:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax/create_audit_ajax.php",
    data: $('#audit_form').serialize(),
    success:function(response){
        window.location = "../standards.php?page=create_audit&auditID="+audit_id;

    },//here, remove it

  });
```

Comment: Ya, IE<8 doesn't like it!

Answer (score 6):

Remove the extra `,` after success callback.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what causes the error but I see a minor fault in your code (extra comma):

```
function go_standards()
  {
    var audit_id = $('#auditID').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax/create_audit_ajax.php",
    data: $('#audit_form').serialize(),
    success:function(response){
        window.location = "../standards.php?page=create_audit&auditID="+audit_id;
    }
  });
 }
```

That should be your function